Как реализовать динамический импорт в Vue3 при использовании ModuleFederataion
Я подключил два приложения через ModuleFederation. Вроде как все работает нормально, все зависимости шарятся, однако работает это только если прописать функцию импорта примерно так:
const loadComponent = () => {
  component.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`app1/test`));
};

Я бы хотел иметь возможность использовать эту функцию для разных компонентов, то есть так:
const loadComponent = (path) => {
  component.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`app1/${path}`));
};

Однако, при использовании второго способа, возникает ошибка:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app1' in 'C:\Users\User\web\host\src'

Причем неважно, редактировать ли строку прямо в функции import, либо заранее прописать пусть через переменную:
const loadComponent = () => {
const path = 'app1/test' 
  component.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(path));
};

Этот вариант тоже не работает.
Возникает предположение, что если в импорт не подать чистую строку, Vue ищет компонент в своей директории, а не в ModuleFederation.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно исправить эту ошибку

Возможно решение является худшим из возможных, однако у меня заработало в случае, когда я обертываю в объект не путь для импорта, а саму функцию import с прописанным путем.
Таким образом, для Vue3 решение будет примерно таким:
const componentList = ref([
  {name: 'patientCard', importFunction: () => import('vaccination/patientCard')}
])

const loadComponent = async(importFunction) => {
  component.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => importFunction());
};

loadComponent(componentList.value[0].importFunction)

По идее, поскольку мы обертываем импорт в функцию внутри объекта, импорт вернет промис только при обращении к самой функции importFunction.

На первый взгляд все это кажется фантастическим. Но!!!
Ответ может быть найден в названии функции defineAsyncComponent(...).
Семантика имени define* предполагает, что возвращаемая переменная предварительно определенная константа, и в контексте динамического загрузчика, функция с таким именем применятся не должна!
Пример выше нарушает семантическую логику. И такого применения мы не найдем на странице справочника Vue.
Вернемся к вопросу: Vue вызывает функции в различных контекстах. А динамический загрузчик loadComponent() предположительно вызывается не в том контексте, который ожидает define*. Почему сработал первый вариант, неясно, если конечно он сработал вообще(в вопросе этого не ясно), но реализацию установки и загрузки компонентов следует пересмотреть.

У меня работает динамическое определение наименования компонента в таком виде (в импорте используйте `` ):
const formComponent = computed(() => params.value['components'][tableName.value] ? defineAsyncComponent(() => import(./modules/${params.value['components'][tableName.value] + '.vue'})) : FormComm)

При моей попытке опубликовать мою функцию точно - Форум не дает использовать - просто их удаляет из записи!  То есть вам нужно ./modules/${params.value['components'][tableName.value] + '.vue'} заключить в обратные кавычки

Возможно проблема не в функции defineAsyncComponent, поскольку функция import не работает вне зависимости от того, где происходит вызов. То есть условно участок кода ниже выдаст ошибку только во втором случае. Причем Импорт из первого случая исправно выдает то, что и должно прийти. Быть может, есть какие-то нюансы с динамическим импортом при работе Vue3 и ModuleFederation?
onMounted(() => {

 //1 случай
 import(`app1/test`);

 //2 случай
 let url = `app1/test`;
 import(url);
});


@Trottenheimer Повторюсь. Функция defineAsyncComponent сама по себе уже создает ленивый загрузчик, при этом не загружая многократно-используемый компонент, ее не используют в контексте реактивности - это приведет к лишним тратам ресурсов и постоянным загрузкам многократно-используемого кода. Использование такого кода - ошибка, даже если методом тыка просто угадать путь. Загруженный компонент добавляется иначе, например это может быть так component.value = h(myAsyncComponent, props). А ранее загруженные компоненты, кешируются Vue для повторных использований - так же как и обычные.

@AlexanderLonberg Даже если так, то как мне получить этот компонент, если импорт из MF не работает с переменными и измененными строками? Главный вопрос не в том, как присвоить компонент, а как его в первую очередь получить

@Trottenheimer Родилась такая мысль: что в реактивном контексте стандартная функция import так же прибавит путь от корня. Vue может этого не понимать, т.к. он вообще не ожидал такого вызова, и загрузчик неверно интерпретирует путь, точнее это ты его запутал. Второй момент куда более интересный: когда мы используем режим dev то мы грузим модули как .vue, но что произойдет после компиляции, когда таких модулей уже нет. Боюсь что работать ничего не будет вообще. Возможно это причина по которой сработал первый случай - бандлер схавал статику, но обработать динамическую строку он не в силах.

@Trottenheimer Кстати подумай на эту тему - как ты собираешься управлять путями в скомпилированном приложении, когда этих путей уже не существует. И откуда будут грузится компоненты. Даже одно это уже говорит, что с функцией loadComponent что-то не так.

@Михаил Откуда в скомпилированном приложении может быть vue - такой код не будет работать.

Я использую Vite и без добавления расширения - + '.vue' выражение работать не будет.
А в том виде, что опубликовано у меня прекрасно работает. В том числе и есть деплой на живой сервер Название Компонента у меня определяется в объекте Таблица - Компонент

@Михаил Я использую Webpack, на Vite перейти возможности, к сожалению, нет.

@AlexanderLonberg, разве не это ли смысл moduleFederation, что хосту могут приходить различные компоненты из различных модулей? Допустим, если один модуль упал, то приложение может работать дальше, а когда модуль встанет - компонент восстановится.

Под Webpack тоже должно работать (раньше использовал). Работаю на PhpSrorm ->  Laravel + Vue3 и использовал laravel-mix
Вы установили vue-loader ?

@Михаил можно поподробнее про ваше решение? Из того что было написано выше у меня вроде как не работает.

Использую Laravel для Серверной части (РНР).
Получаю по запросу - Axios - Файл со стартовыми параметрами для Админки с сервера (объект).
Сохраняю его в переменную params.

@Михаил Я получаю компоненты не с бэкенда, а с другого фронтенд приложения

@Trottenheimer Я не использовал moduleFederation, но их справка так же не содержит подобных примеров загрузки, и у них есть собственная функция createRemoteComponent, которая как раз внутри себя правильно вызывает defineAsyncComponent. Вот такие примеры и надо использовать, а не искать костыли.

Так Компоненты и у меня во фронте - просто из бэка получаю параметры какой-какому нужно открывать (можете это вообще в const статически задать и не получать).
Возможно возникает у вас вопрос асинхронности - не получили а уже запрашиваете по адресу.
Может все упростить и просто Компоненты нужные включить в текущий проект?

Посмотрите вот https://module-federation.io/practice/bridge/vue-bridge -может поможет для вашего случая (я не использовал никогда module-federation)

@Михаил То что бандлер схавал путь и может его разрешать это хорошо. Но, мы загружает строковый код, браузер разбирает его в AST, JS компилирует байт-код, после этого его может принять Vue. Спрашивается: Зачем мы это делаем несколько раз когда используем такие необдуманные решения с многократным вызовом defineAsyncComponent()? Смысл define* определить ленивый загрузчик и при первом использовании компонента загрузить и сделать все один раз. Именно поэтому эту функцию назвали define*, а не load*. Эта функция не несет никакой нагрузки, она хранит только путь и не потребляет ресурсов.
